# Segmentation Fault , dynamically allocating a structure inside a dynamically allocated structure

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, structure, project, dynamic-memory-allocation

**Here is my complete code**.... it's a big one,and ***thanks for your time***.

***https://pastebin.com/Uj97g357***

In the code above I want to know the exact reason why I'm failing to dynamically allocate the memory for the structure inside a structure.I usually compete in *codechef,hackerrank,codeforces*.However,I'm new to doing some projects like these...I've debugged a bit so I've found where the mistake was,but I couldn't rectify it and I couldn't sleep peacefully...If you find the reason please let me know and **Help me outcome it** !!

**In short my code is,for people who have less time to spare** :) :-

```
struct subject
{
    struct DateTime StartTime,EndTime;   //Don't bother about these structure definitions
    string ClassName,ClassType;
    int ThresholdPercentage,MaxPossiblePercentage;
    struct Note notes;                  //Don't bother about these structure definitions
};
struct students
{
    struct subject *subjects;
    string name;
    int MaxSubjects;
} *student;

int main(void)
{
    int NStudents,Subjects,i,j;
    cout<<"Enter Number of Students:- ";
    cin>>NStudents;
    student=(struct students*)malloc(sizeof(struct students)*(NStudents+1));
    cout<<'\n';
    for(i=1;i<=NStudents;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Number of Subjects for "<<i<<" Student:- ";
        cin>>Subjects;
        student[i].MaxSubjects=Subjects;
        student[i].subjects=(struct subject*)malloc(sizeof(struct subject)*(Subjects+1));   
        cout<<'\n';
        for(j=1;j<=Subjects;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter the name of Subject "<<j<<" :- ";

            cin>>student[i].subjects[j].ClassName;//<<<==================FAULT HERE.
        }
    PrintStudentSubjects(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Actual Problem**

```
    struct subject
{
    struct DateTime StartTime,EndTime;   //Don't bother about these structure definitions
    string ClassName,ClassType;
    int ThresholdPercentage,MaxPossiblePercentage;
    struct Note notes;                  //Don't bother about these structure definitions
};
struct students
{
    struct subject *subjects;
    string name;
    int MaxSubjects;
} *student;

student=(struct students*)malloc(sizeof(struct students)*(NStudents+1));
student[i].subjects=(struct subject*)malloc(sizeof(struct subject)*(Subjects+1));//<<== In a loop..
```

This gives me a Segmentation Fault...can't I use malloc?,If not why?..If yes,how come enlighten me  :)  .

Comment: Don't use malloc.  Don't use raw pointers.  Instead, use a `std::vector<student>`, which has a member `std::vector<subject>`.

Comment: So using a malloc wouldn't work?

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: You should index your arrays from 0 to n-1, not from 1 to n.

Comment: No, `malloc` in C++ doesn't work. (Unless you're an expert and really know what you're doing.)

Comment: I'll edit it now to make it short...and coming to your point well,I've declared my array to 0,n+1 so that I can use from 1 to n :) .

Comment: You might also want to post the exact error message - I'm not a C++ user but in general, that helps. Welcome to SO, btw.

Comment: `sizeof(struct students)*NStudents+1` should be `sizeof(struct students)*(NStudents+1)`.  `sizeof(struct subject)*Subjects+1` should be `sizeof(struct subject)*(Subjects+1)`.  If you insist on wasting memory to start indexing at 1, that is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out...I'll change it...however my question still stands...

Comment: Why don't you try it before deciding that it doesn't help ?

Comment: Well,When yesterday I've tried using a 0-indexed array....so am I sure that it doesn't work though I correct the mistake you've highlighted.

Comment: `malloc` is a C library function, it doesn't know anything about C++ constructors. The `std::string` member variables don't get properly initialized and then your code crashes when you try to use them. I'll be the third person in the comments to say don't use `malloc`.

Comment: I was almost the fourth.

Comment: The reason is just what you said I guess....well thanks for that :) .I just changed it to char array and it worked...thanks once again @Blastfurnace .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc()` doesn't call the constructor for your classes.  Use `new`.

```
student = new students[NStudents+1];
student[i].subjects = new subject[Subjects+1];
```

Comment: Worked....Thanks,I'm new here....I was like banged my head to keyboard all yesterday and yet in a couple of minutes it solved in here..and I've got to know the reason as well.....This Community is great....Thanks again....and can someone tell me how to close this problem??...it would be a waste of others time if it's still on right..

Comment: No need to close.  Just leave it like it is.